SwiftUI presentationDetent sheet top is not visible
In code below, top of GridView is not visible when sheet is presented in .medium scale, and visible when expanded to .large.  How can I ensure that top of GridView is always visible regardless of detent scale?  I've tried a bunch of things with padding, spacers, frames, etc...but not able to get the right result.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showGrid = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showGrid.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show grid")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showGrid) {
            GridView()
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct GridView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible())
        ]
        
        VStack() {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 2) {
                ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { index in
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 50)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


In your sheet/GridView, try making the whole container a ScrollView instead of a VStack.

I tried it and that should do it. It's works in conjunction with .defaultScrollAnchor, which seems to be .top by default, but you can have it start displaying the sheet content from further down.

Worked for me also.  Thanks for the tip, will mark as the answer.

Answer from Cenk Bilgen worked for me.
